# Drop-down List in MVC 3

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

After looking at many examples of drop-down menus, here's my situation.

I have a database table: `Companies`

In my registration view model, I have the following:  `public int? CompanyId { get; set; }` (thought about changing this to `public IEnumerable<Company> Companies { get; set; }`)

In my registration view, the user can select which company he works for.  I would like to have a drop-down list of what companies are in our database for the user to select from.

I have a company repository set up to get all companies and return as an `IEnumerable`.

How do I approach this? Would I be better off doing this in the view model or the controller?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your model, declare two properties.

```
public int? CompanyId { get; set; }
public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Companies { get; set; }
```

Then in your view

```
@Html.LabelFor(x => x.CompanyId)
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.CompanyId, Model.Companies)
```

This will create a select list that will set your CompanyId property and use the Companies as the option values.

You can create the SelectList easily enough. I'm guessing it would be something like

```
Companies.AddRange(
  aListOfCompanies.Select(x => 
    new SelectListItem { Text = x.CompanyName, Value = x.CompanyId.ToString() }));
```

Comment: Where would I put the `SelectList`?

Comment: @edmastermind29, the `Companies` property? It would be in your model. You could set the value in the constructor of the model, or in your controller.

Comment: @edmastermind29 you could also you the AjaxDropdown (http://awesome.codeplex.com), this way you don't have to put the list of SelectListItem in the ViewModel only the id (because the list of items will be loaded via ajax)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. On a unrelated note, I feel so honored to have Chuck Norris comment ;)

Answer (score 0):

Create a method in your ViewModel like(GetCompanies())
then in your Controller make a SelectList object with what it return your viewModel object.
then you can pass it to the view by viewBag or a property in your model.